# Getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'doFileHasCorrectFileExtension' of undefined " from ES6 class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class, ecmascript-6

I am encountering a problem where I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'doFileHasCorrectFileExtension' of undefined`
when I create an file or an folder. I expect my application to be able to use
the method `doFileHasCorrectFileExtension` without having it being undefined.

As an attempt to solve my problem I created an variable that hold the object
created by the class.

```js
const textFileWatcher = new FileExtensionMatcher("Text files", [
  "txt",
]);
```

My second attempt to solve the problem was to set the watcher variable
(`textFileWatcher` in the previous attempt) in the global object so it doesn't
get garbage collected.

```js
const watchers: FileExtensionMatcher[] = [];
watchers.push(
  new FileExtensionMatcher("Text files", [
    "txt",
  ])
);

//@typescript-ignore
global.fileWatcher = watchers;
```

Additionally, to diagnose the issue, I fired up the debugger on my script and
I realised that `this` is somehow undefined in the method `onFilesChanged`.

Here is the full error message I am having:

```
PS C:\Users\ASD\Project\js\download-sort> typescript-node .\source\
Debugger attached.
[16:13:32] Started listening file watcher for Text files
[16:13:46] New Text Document (2).txt has been created at C:\Users\ASD\Downloads.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'doFileHasCorrectFileExtension' of undefined
    at C:\Users\ASD\Project\js\download-sort\source\FileExtensionMatcher.typescript:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\ASD\Project\js\download-sort\source\FileExtensionMatcher.typescript:4:12)
    at C:\Users\ASD\Project\js\download-sort\source\FileExtensionMatcher.typescript:45:56
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at onFilesChanged (C:\Users\ASD\Project\js\download-sort\source\FileExtensionMatcher.typescript:45:11)
```

Here is the code of the class:

```js
import nsfw, { ActionType } from "nsfw";
import log from "fancy-log";
import chalk from "chalk";

export default class FileExtensionMatcher
{
  /**
   * Add a new extension to the filter
   */
  public set extensions(ext: string)
  {
    this.Regex.push(new RegExp(`$\.${ext}`));
  }

  private Regex: RegExp[] = [];
  /**
   * The name of the filter
   */
  public Name: string;

  constructor(name: string, extension: string[])
  {
    this.Name = name;
    nsfw("C:/Users/ASD/Downloads", this.onFilesChanged, { errorCallback: log.error }).then((fileWatcher) =>
    {
      fileWatcher.start().then(() => log("Started listening file watcher for " + this.Name));
    });
    extension.forEach((extension) => this.extensions = extension);
  }

  public doFileHasCorrectFileExtension(file: string): boolean
  {
    if (file === undefined)
      return false;
      
    for (const fileExtension of this.Regex)
    {
      if (fileExtension.test(file))
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  public onFilesChanged(files: nsfw.FileChangeEvent[])
  {
    console.log(this);
    files.forEach(async (file: nsfw.FileChangeEvent) =>
    {
      let fileName: undefined | string;
      switch (file.action)
      {
        case ActionType.CREATED:
        case ActionType.DELETED:
        case ActionType.MODIFIED:
          fileName = '"' + file?.file + '"';

        case ActionType.CREATED:
          log.info(chalk`{underline ${file.file}} has been {yellow created} at {underline ${file.directory}}.`);
          {
            if (this.doFileHasCorrectFileExtension(file.file) && file.file !==  undefined) /* TypeError: Cannot read property 'doFileHasCorrectFileExtension' of undefined
    at C:\Users\ASD\Project\js\download-sort\source\FileExtensionMatcher.typescript:8:71 */
            {
              console.log(file.file);
            }
          }
          break;
        case ActionType.DELETED:
          log.info(chalk`{underline ${file.file}} has been {yellow deleted}.`);
          break;
        case ActionType.MODIFIED:
          log.info(chalk`{underline ${file.file}} has been {yellow modified}.`);
          break;
        case ActionType.RENAMED:
          log.info(chalk`{underline ${file.oldFile}} got {yellow renamed} to {underline ${file.newFile}}`);
          break;
      }
    });
  }
};

new FileExtensionMatcher("Text files", [
  "txt",
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the second parameter on the function `nsfw` to `(filesChanged) => this.onFilesChanged(filesChanged)`. Here is how it look in my code:

```js
  constructor(name: string, extension: string[])
  {
    this.Name = name;
    nsfw("C:/Users/ASD/Downloads", (filesChanged) => this.onFilesChanged(filesChanged), { errorCallback: log.error }).then((fileWatcher) =>
    {
      fileWatcher.start().then(() => log("Started listening file watcher for " + this.Name));
    });
    this.onFilesChanged = this.onFilesChanged.bind(this);
    extension.forEach((extension) => this.extensions = extension);
  }
```

The problem was that the method onFilesChanged couldn't acess the class environement because it was bound to the `nsfw` function object. Doing my fix work because it
s the arrow function environement that is bounded to nsfw object and not the method environement.

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the correct `this` by passing it into `nsfw` - use `this.onFilesChanged.bind(this)`

Comment: I am still having the error. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/jJXxSbXL 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ViniDalvino look at your 2nd argument thats what is happening, not in the other function